# Как сделать чтобы бот парсил все сообщения из одного канала в другой Discord (логирования канала)

Tags: python, discord

Задача в том чтобы бот переадресовывал в форме ембед все сообщения из одного канала в другой заданный мной канал (В режиме реального времени)

Задать в коде ид канала из которого будут копироватся все сообщения
Задать ид канала в который должна идти переадресация сообщения
Задать исключения пользователей от которых сообщения не будут переадресовываться

Comment: Подобные задачи допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой код, в него можно ещё много чего добавить, особенно если использовать другие ивенты по типу `on_message_edit` или `on_message_delete`:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel == ид канала из которого копируются сообщения:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Новое сообщение',
            description=f'{message.content}\nАвтор: {message.author}',
            color=0xFF0033
        )

        await bot.get_channel(ид канала в который отправляем эмбед).send(embed=embed)
```